# Why array of struct lets me index to out of boundary array

Tags: c, arrays

Sorry for the bad title and i am new to the C but here is the part i don't understand.

I have a simple struct;

```
struct st{

        int a;
        int b;
};
```

and i am creating array of struct and indexing values to variable 'a' in main;

```
int main(){
         struct st st_arr[2];
         st_arr[0].a = 5;
         st_arr[1].a = 10;
         st_arr[4].a = 20;

         printf("%d %d %d\n", st_arr[0].a, st_arr[1].a, st_arr[4].a);
}
```

i have assigned 2 array of structs but it lets me index 4th of the struct why is that? Isn't it suppose to give me an error?

the output is:

5 10 20

Comment: Because there is nobody checking that you go out of bounds,,,,

Comment: It is called _undefined behavior_ meaning it can go wrong, it can go right, your program may abort or anything else can happen, either immediately or at a later stage in your program.

Comment: I know you wanted to be sure but it's important to understand that `st_arr[2]` is already out of bounds, despite its resemblance to the array definition.

Comment: thank you so much for your answers

Answer (score 1):

C does not provide a(ny) bound checking by default.

Accessing out of bounds (i.e., invalid memory) is defined to have [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Maybe you should change "defined" to "specified" so that I can get back out of the rabbit hole ;-)

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider That was intentional. :)